# How to Call Javascript to c#

Tags: javascript, c#

How to run javascript file in c#
I have tried ....How to call c# method from js functionHow to call c# method from js functionHow to call c# method from js functionHow to call c# method from js functionHow to call c# method from js functionHow to call c# method from js functionHow to call c# method from js functionHow to call c# method from js functionHow to call c# method from js functionHow to call c# method from js function

> 

```js
   function SavePSD(saveFile){
        psdSaveOptions = new PhotoshopSaveOptions();
        psdSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
        psdSaveOptions.alphaChannels = true; 
        activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, psdSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
        }
 
 
    function OutFoldPSD(dname){
        var outfolder = new Folder("D:/Daimond Classic/Saved/")
           if (outfolder.exists == false){
                outfolder.create();
                var saveFile = new File(outfolder + "/" + dname +".psd");
                 SavePSD(saveFile);}
           else{
               var saveFile = new File(outfolder + "/" + dname +".psd");
               SavePSD(saveFile);}
                    }
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function Func() {
        alert("Save Complete!")
    }
```

Comment: What's the repeated blurb  in your question? It hurts readability. You could use that space to explain the problem, or what happened when you ran your code vs what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible, they are two completely seperate languages. You would have to use something called a Application Programming Interface that is written to communicate between different programs or people.

More information can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface